# Customizing the series data in pie charts with a dynamic json series (HighCharts)

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I am fairly new to Highcharts. I have a pie chart that is being rendered fine with dynamic data (JSON String) . But I want to customize certain slices to be Sliced: true and Selected: True. I am not sure how to do it. Please find my code as below,

```
<div id="container_${page_id}" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>




var series = [];
var total = 0;
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
            series.push([value.statisticData+'_'+value.sizes,parseInt(value.sizes)]);
            console.log("statisticData",value.statisticData);
            console.log("value.sizes",value.sizes);
            total += parseInt(value.count);
        });


        var chartSessionStatus = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: $("#container_"+testSessionPageId).get(0),                        
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: true,
                buttons: {
                    contextButton: {
                        menuItems: [{
                            text: 'Statistics',
                        }]
                    }}
                },

            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.point.name.split('_')[0] + ': <b>'+this.y+'</b>';
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: '<h4 style="font-style: bold">Tenant Statistics</h4>'
            },
            legend: {
                    labelFormatter: function() {
                        return this.name.split('_')[0] + ' (' + this.y+')';
               }
            },

            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        distance: 0,
                        useHTML: true,
                        formatter: function() {
                            if( this.y > 0)
                                return '<b>'+this.point.name.split('_')[0] +'('+ this.y +')</b>';
                        }
                    },
                    showInLegend: true,
                    size: 150
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Tenant Statistics',
                data: series
            }]
        });

    });
```

**Main point of concern, in the series , I have the option for data as "data : series" but I would like to customize certain slices in this series. But since the data is dynamic I am not sure how to use only certain parts of the json string** 
The Json that i receive is in the following format :

[{"statisticData":"Tests Created","sizes":"3"},{"statisticData":"Students","sizes":"2"},{"statisticData":"Users","sizes":"7"},{"statisticData":"Schools","sizes":"10"}]

Any Help is greatly appreciated !!! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

After getting json, you can parse it / add slice parameter and then use in highcharts. So instead of pushing :`series.push([value.statisticData+'_'+value.sizes,parseInt(value.sizes)]);`

you can push something like:

```
series.push({
        name: value.statisticData+'_'+value.sizes,
        y: parseInt(value.sizes),
        sliced: true,
        selected: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for the reply. This does work but it makes all the slices true, I want only 1 of the slices ( pie chart value ) sliced or rather selected . Is there a way to do that as well ? 
Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: So add any condition, which will "decide" if it should be sliced or not. All is up to you.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, could you give me an example of how to add a condition in there ? As i said i am fairly new to this

Comment: But which slices should be sliced which should be ? how you define it? ONly what you need is use IF.

Comment: I tried to use the if condition , but I am getting an error, please find my code snippet above as the 2nd answer .

Comment: If I am trying to use the IF condition within the series.push I am getting an error. I just want to see that if value.statisticData == "Students Created" that slice should be sliced and selected .